# Apache caching problem

Tags: apache, node.js

I'm loading some json through apache as per:

http://arguments.callee.info/2010/04/20/running-apache-and-node-js-together/

The JSON however is outdated when I use the apache url. The node.js :8000 url serves the correct data.

How can I make sure apache doesn't cache json?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to setup the expire headers to the past and make sure that the browser does not cache nay json via cache-control haders for json files and 
You can try to add this to your apache config file :

```
<FilesMatch "\.(json|json)$">
     Header set Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
     Header set Pragma "no-cache"
     Header set Expires "Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT"
 </FilesMatch>
```

The mod_headers module will need to be installed in Apache to use this method.

If you are interested you can have a read at the roots

http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9

Comment: Thanks, this is the kind of solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can append a "cache killer" on the URL you are fetching asynchronously. That is some value that will always make the URL unique.

```
var url = "http://example.com/service.json?" + new Date().getTime();
```